# Implementing Switch with Python: 'null is not callable'

Tags: python, switch-statement, callable

I've read some other answers about implementing the switch/case in python and i'm trying to fit this in my code without success:

```
f = open(prg)

line = f.readline()  
splitting = line.split(" ", 1)
options = {"PUSH": push, "POP": pop, "ADD": add, "SUB": sub, 
           "MUL": mul, "DIV": div, "INPUT": inpt, "OUTPUT": outp,
           "EXIT": ext}
options[splitting[0]](splitting[1])
```

I'll implement one function per element on the dictionary.

The problem is that the IDE says: 'null is not callable' on  `options[splitting[0]](splitting[1])`.

EDIT: I've been trying several ways to call the functions from the dictionary and i've found strange behavior:
This code:

```
    choice = "PUSH 1"
splitted = choice.split(" ", 1)
options = {"PUSH": push, "POP": pop, "ADD": add, "SUB": sub, "MUL": mul, "DIV": div, "INPUT": inpt, "OUTPUT": outp,
                "EXIT": ext}

options["PUSH"]
```

Is not correct since the last statement "have no effect" says PyCharm.
However if i enclose it on a try/catch statement this disappears and it disappears even if i do something like this:

```
options.get("PUSH", lambda: None)()
```

Even if i figure out how to select the correct function, how do i pass the parameters to them?
I'm puzzled.

Comment: The error means that `splitting[0]` is not actually in the dictionary. Can you show the contents of the file (the first line)?

Comment: Try to print value of `splitting[0]`.

Comment: Only the IDE is showing the problem? Did you execute the code? Because when i tried through shell its working.

Comment: HI Thanks everyone. i've figured out the problem. The thing is that i've got no file to test yet. I'm going to try with line = something i'll find on the file and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values of your dictionary are functions. If so, you have to add brackets to the calling:

```
options["PUSH"]()`
```

For the parameters handling I'll suggest you to pass the whole splitted list to the function and handle it there.

```
def push(splitted_list):
    param = splitted_list[1]
    #do something....

options = {"PUSH": push, "POP": pop, "ADD": add, "SUB": sub, "MUL": mul, "DIV": div, "INPUT": inpt, "OUTPUT": outp,
            "EXIT": ext}

choise = "PUSH 1"
splitted = choise.split(" ")
options[splitted[0]](splitted)
```

This will call the push function with the splitted list and do something with the parameter that was passed with the call.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I'm going mad. I've got PyCharm community edition 3.4.1 running for python 2.7.8. The statement options[splitted[0]](splitted) GIVES ERROR "null is not callable". Your code AND this simple test. >>> def test(n): 
 print n

 
>>> test(5)
5
>>> d={'test':test}
>>> d['test'](5) ---> 'NULL' IS NOT CALLABLE I'm gonna open a thread for this right now.

Comment: @gargiulo2000, Daniel's answer and your 'test' works for me with WingIDE, so looks like PyCharm has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
(splitting[1])
```

Is your problem.

```
options[splitting[0]]
```

Returns you an entry in your 'options' dict and then you use "(splitting[1])" on that, note your use of "()", depending on what entry you get back from 'options' you might be able to use "[]".

Try this:

```
    splitting = ['PUSH', 'POP', 'DIR']
    options = {"PUSH": 'push', "POP": 'pop', "ADD": 'add', "SUB": 'sub', 
               "MUL": 'mul', "DIV": 'div', "INPUT": 'inp', "OUTPUT": 'out',
               "EXIT": 'ext', "DIR": {'A': 'something'}}

    options[splitting[2]]
    options[splitting[2]]['A']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but this code does not address my need. with the (splitting[1]) my hope was to pass the parameter at the function.

Comment: And even if i wouldn't need functions to be called after keys in the dictionary, on your code the callings on the keys shows me an error: "Statement seems to have no effect."